# How to add horizontal scrollbar to select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

In `select2` if the selected option doesn't fit the select it is cut off with ellipses `...`

But I want it to add a horizontal bar scroll bar instead, without upsetting the positioning of anything on the screen.

How can I do this?

Adding `overflow-x: scroll;` to `select {` doesn't work, nor does adding it to various of the `select2` classes.

Comment: `overflow-x: scroll` should work. Either you're not targeting the right element or the cascading order is not as expected. Just make sure your CSS file comes after the select2 CSS and the default styling is overridden. Please inspect to make sure what happens with the overflow property.

Comment: I put my css after select2 css like you said but the problem remains.  A scroll track appears below the select but if the text is too long, it's cut off with ellipses instead of adding a scroll bar to the empty track.

Comment: Did you try **!improtant** tag while overriding the overflow-x: scroll?

just Try this and tell what you are getting.If you can share the detailed code,should be helpful.

select{

overflow-x:scroll !important;

}

Comment: Please provide a simple reproducible example or a codepen link so that we can have a look.

Comment: codepen wasn't acting like it loaded the `select2` `js` and `css` and `jquery` (I'm not familiar with it) but if you simply make a select `<select><option value='testing 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10'>testing 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10</option></select>` then do `$('select').select2()` and add `select{ overflow-x:scroll !important; }` to the `css`, it illustrates the problem.  It cuts it off at the digit `7` and adds `...` to the end.